# enum as return type of a function in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashtable, enumeration

Following java method returns keys of hashtable as Enumeration.

```
Hashtable<String, Object> props = new Hastable<String, Object>(); 

// some code here

public final Enumeration getPropertyURIs() {
    return props.keys();
}
```

I want to translate this code to C++.

More specifically, how can I implement the same function in C++ which returns enum of keys of std::map?

Comment: I don't know java, but I suspect that enumerations in C++ are _not even close_ to enumerations in Java. `enum`s in C++ are just a convenient way to list out some constants, giving each one a unique value.

Comment: What does "enum of keys" mean? In C++, the key of a map has a fixed type, and you can only speak about that type. (The key type *may* of course be an enum.)

Comment: might be duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110157/how-to-retrieve-all-keys-or-values-from-a-stdmap)

Comment: @fmass: The solution there applies, but the question is different.

Comment: I'm not sure why C++ `enum` != Java `Enumeration` is discussed at all. Java `enum` is exactly identical to C++ `enum`, but  `Enumeration` is something completely different which only accidentially contains 3 identical letters in its name. The closest thing to an `Enumeration` in C++ is an iterator.

Comment: @Damon ah ok, news to me. As I said, I don't know java :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `enum` in C++ is just a collection of constants.

Do you mean something like this, perhaps?

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::any> props_t;
props_t props;

std::vector<std::string> getPropertyURIs()
{
   std::vector<std::string> keys;
   for (props_t::const_iterator i = props.begin(); i != props.end(); ++i)
   {
      keys.push_back(i->first);
   }
   return keys;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer it if `getPropertyURIs` would take an output-iterator (whose type is a template-parameter` as input, and write the keys in there instead of returning a `vector`.

Comment: This might be what the OP thought he needed, but this sort of thing is probably just unnecessary in C++. If you need the keys, you just iterate over the map directly...

Comment: Or call `for_each()` with a variant of [`select1st<>`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/select1st.html).

Comment: @AndréCaron: From the page you linked: *This function object is an SGI extension; it is not part of the C++ standard.*

Comment: @BjörnPollex: I know.  That's why I said *a variant of ...*.  This function object is trivial to implement.

Comment: @sufyansiddique: Note that this returns a `vector` by value, meaning that an additional copy of the entire keyset is created. This copy will probably be optimized away in most cases, but you should be aware that this is not generally the case. C++ does not have reference-semantics like Java.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing you could get would be to return an iterator. The problem there is that you actually need two iterators to specify a range. One way to get around this is by using an output-iterator:

```
template<class output_iterator_type>
void getPropertyURIs(output_iterator_type out) {
    // loop copied from @dalle
    for (props_t::const_iterator i = keys.begin(); i != keys.end(); ++i)
    {
        *out = i->first;
        ++out;
    }
}
```

If you now want to store all the keys in a `vector`, you can do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> keys;
getPropertyURIs(std::back_inserter(keys));
```