# finding elements of set in a map

Tags: c++

I have two maps, `tk1` and `tk2` with the following structure:

```
std::map<std::string, double>tk1;
std::map<std::string, double>tk2;
```

`tk1` contains the following data:

```
    2011-01-03 2200
    2011-01-04 2209
    2011-01-05 2300
```

and `tk2` contains the following data:

```
2011-01-03 2450
2011-01-04 2465
2011-01-06 2476
2011-01-07 2457
```

I have created a set that contains the dates as strings as in

```
std::set<std::string>dateset;
std::set<std::string>new_dateset;
```

I created it by iterating through the 2 maps and inserting into the set as in

```
dateset.insert(it->first);
```

`dateset` has the following values:

```
2011-01-03
2011-01-04
2011-01-05
2011-01-06
2011-01-07
```

I want to populate new_dateset so it only contains the dates that are in both `tk1` and `tk2`, i.e. new_dateset should contain only

```
2011-01-03
2011-01-04
```

I wrote the following:

```
std::set<std::string>::iterator it1=dateset.begin(), end1=dateset.end();
std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it2=tk1.begin(), end2=tk1.end();
std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it3=tk2.begin(), end3=tk2.end();
while (it1 != end1) {
if (it2->first == *it1) 
new_dateset.insert(it2->first);
++it1;
}
```

but obviously I am not doing it correctly. Can someone suggest the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over `it1`, check if `first` for each element is in `tk2` using the `find()` method, and insert it into the set if it is there. What you are doing in your example is to check elements in `dataset`, which contain keys that are in `tk1` OR `tk2`.

```
for(; it2 != end2; ++it2) {
  if(tk2.find(it2->first) != end3) new_dataset.insert(it2->first);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might consider `std::set_intersection` with the `key_iterator` from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2389291/179910).

Comment: The dates are the keys of a `std::map`, so they are already sorted.

Comment: Good point -- I sort of knew that, then my memory quit working, and I edited the "If you can depend..." into it, even though it didn't make any real sense. Thanks for reminding me of reality! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should compare strings as follows:

```
if(it2->first.compare(*it) == 0)
{
  //strings match, do something.
}
else
{
  // no match do something else.
}
```

Comment: Why? It's more verbose, less clear than plain == and does the same thing here.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over elements in tk1 and see if the keys exist in `tk2`. If it does, then insert.

```
for(; it2 != end2; ++it2)
{
  if(tk2.find(it2->first) != end3)
  {
    new_dataset.insert(it2->first);
  }
}
```