# Iterator over a vector of pairs and use std::copy to print the result

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have the following vector:

`std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string>> songs;`

I want to use std::copy to pass elements from the vector (let's say the int) to ostream, something like the following which ofcourse doesn't work:

`std::copy(songs.begin(),songs.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,""));`

I know that I can do it with this way:

```
for(auto it=songs.begin(); it!=songs.end(); ++it)
    {
      std::cout << (*it).first;
    }
```

But I am wondering if it possible in C++ to create an iterator that points only to one of the elements of the pair and then use it to iterate and copy the elements to ostream or how can I make the std::copy above work?

Comment: You can use `std::transform` to return the first element of each pair.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve all keys (or values) from a std::map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110157/how-to-retrieve-all-keys-or-values-from-a-stdmap) which has pointers to `select1st`, boost range's filter adaptor and `boost::transform_iterator`, all of which can be used to solve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As chris [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752683/iterator-over-a-vector-of-pairs-and-use-stdcopy-to-print-the-result#comment24131720_16752683) in the comments, the easiest solution is to use `std::transform`

```
std::transform( songs.begin(), songs.end(), 
                std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "\n" ),
                []( decltype(v)::value_type const& p ) -> decltype(p.first) {
                    return p.first;
                }
              );
```

If you want to go the custom iterator route, create a type that mimics `ostream_iterator`'s behavior, and additionally uses `std::get` to retrieve only the item you care about.

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct get_tuple_item_iterator
: public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{   
    get_tuple_item_iterator( std::ostream& os, std::string term )
    : os_(os)
    , term_(std::move(term))
    {}

    template<typename... T>
    get_tuple_item_iterator& operator=( std::tuple<T...> const& elem )
    {
        static_assert(N < sizeof...(T), "N is out of range");
        os_ << std::get<N>( elem ) << term_;
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    get_tuple_item_iterator& operator=( std::pair<T1, T2> const& elem )
    {
        static_assert((N == 0) || (N == 1), "N must be 0 or 1 for std::pair");
        return operator=( std::tie( elem.first, elem.second ) );
    }

    get_tuple_item_iterator& operator*() { return *this; }
    get_tuple_item_iterator& operator++() { return *this; }
    get_tuple_item_iterator& operator++( int ) { return *this; }

private:
    std::ostream& os_;
    std::string term_;
};
```

Use it as

```
std::copy( songs.begin(), songs.end(), 
           get_tuple_item_iterator<0>( std::cout, "\n" ) );
```