# Is it possible to initialize a vector from the keys in a map?

Tags: c++, c++11

[How to retrieve all keys (or values) from a std::map and put them into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110157/how-to-retrieve-all-keys-or-values-from-a-stdmap) covers the ways to populate a std::vector from the keys in a map pre-C++11.

Is there a way to do this in C++11 using lambdas, etc, that means we can do it in one line so we can initialize the vector from the map instead of create a vector and populate it in 2 actions?

e.g. `vector<int> v(???(m.begin(),m.end()));`

Pure C++11 is preferred but boost is acceptable... the aim is to do this in one line without it being overly complicated and "showing off", so it's not confusing to other developers.

For comparison the "obvious" C++11 solution is:

```
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(m.size()); //not always needed
for(auto &x : map)
  v.push_back(x.first)
```

Comment: [An answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2794168/183120) in that post already has a C++11 solution.

Comment: A solution, but not necessarily the best.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`boost::adaptor::map_keys`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_keys.html) in Boost.Range.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>

int main()
{
    const std::map<int, std::string> m = {
        {1, "Alice"},
        {2, "Bob"},
        {3, "Carol"}
    };

    auto key_range = m | boost::adaptors::map_keys;
    const std::vector<int> v(key_range.begin(), key_range.end());

    for (int x : v) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: You may like to use `boost::copy_range` function here to save some typing.

Comment: I don't like the function. More better approach is use `as_container` in my library.
`const std::vector<int> v = m | map_keys | as_container;`
https://github.com/faithandbrave/OvenToBoost
But, this is not include in Boost.Range yet. (now proposing)

Comment: Yep, your `as_container` is better than `copy_range`.

Comment: This looks cool, but I'm not sure it fulfills the "not confusing" requirement for vanilla C++11 users :p

Comment: `map_keys` behavior is documented. Any approach need understand.

Answer (score 4):

There you go, C++11 one-liner :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::map<int, std::string> map {
        {1, "one"},
        {2, "two"},
        {3, "three"}
    };
    std::vector<int> keys;


    // Reserve enough space (constant-time)
    keys.reserve(map.size());

    // Retrieve the keys and store them into the vector
    std::transform(map.begin(), map.end(), std::back_inserter(keys),
        [](decltype(map)::value_type const &pair) {return pair.first;}
    );//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Will benefit from C++14's auto lambdas


    // Display the vector
    std::copy(keys.begin(), keys.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```

`std::transform` is freaking powerful.

Comment: As I mentioned, `back_inserter` is going to resize the vector for you causing multiple memory allocations and data copies. It is also going to increment the element counter on each element. You have none of these performance detrimental operations when using transform iterators.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin fixed. What do you mean by "element counter" ?

Comment: The number of elements contained in the `vector` and reported by `vector::size`. `push_back` keeps incrementing it. This is cheap, but not free.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Can you explain how your answer avoids resizing the vector's storage?

Comment: @Oktalist : he uses `vector`'s constructor, which in turn will directly `reserve()` based on `std::distance(it1, it2)`. Maxim : I don't think a single increment would even be measurable...

Comment: @Oktalist When passing forward iterators to `vector`'s constructor it allocates storage once, sets data members to its final values and then invokes `uninitialized_copy`.

Comment: @Quentin Single increment per element inserted.

Comment: `map::iterator` is not a `RandomAccessIterator`, so `std::distance` is not free either.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin that's what I meant.

Comment: You see how simple one-liner with `back_inserter` is fraught with performance issues. That `vector::reserve` makes performance better, however it now clutters your code. You don't get such issues with transform iterators. I am not sure `transform` is even warranted here, you can instead do straight-forward range-for-loop: `for(auto& kv : m) keys.push_back(kv.first)` - easier to type, easier to read.

Comment: @Oktalist This is essentially `std::distance(<bidirectional-iterators>)` vs multiple memory allocations and data copies on `vector::push_back()`. Choose your poison.

Comment: I'm not sure N incrementations (if they ever take place, which is not even guaranteed) make this "fraught with performance issues". Boost iterators sure are neat and all, but I'm aiming at the vanilla solution here.

Comment: _performance issues_ - multiple memory allocations and data copies. And increment is the least of my worries, but still it is not free, however negligible.

Comment: I had forgotten the `reserve()` call, yes. Now that I fixed it on your own advice, you can stop ranting about allocation and copies...

Comment: You added `reserve()` call and it is not a one-liner any more. You could even appreciate now the beauty of the transform iterator version  which essentially does `reserve()` for you... I think people use C++ because they do care about allocations and data copies, otherwise they use easier languages.

Comment: I'd love to see how yours is a one-liner. Just replace the semicolon with a comma and mine is, if that matters so much to you. Perhaps I'll dedicate a statue to Boost iterators another day.

Comment: This seems to fail in terms of requiring multiple lines, and being overly complex. A simple `for(auto x : map){...}` is probably less code and way simpler.

Comment: @John I don't think constructing and populating an `std::vector` in one single line as seen in OP's post is possible at all with the standard library only. So, this answer is more of a vanilla C++11 reference implementation. Which, granted, would be nicer without that ugly parameter type for the lambda.

Comment: @John Meh, one line solutions are cool and all, but this one has the benefit of not requiring an external library (although everyone should be using Boost). As for the lambda parameter name, maybe `decltype(map)::value_type const&` is more palatable?

Comment: @Praetorian it has the certain advantage not to repeat template arguments. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following would do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, int> m{{"abc", 1}, {"def", 2}};
    auto extractor = [](decltype(m)::value_type const& kv) { return kv.first; };
    std::vector<std::string> v(
          boost::make_transform_iterator(m.begin(), extractor)
        , boost::make_transform_iterator(m.end(), extractor)
        );
}
```

Note that passing iterators to `vector`'s constructor is the most efficient way to initialize a `vector` compared to solutions that use `push_back` or `resize` a vector filling it with default values first.

Answer (score 2):

*No*, there's no way to do this in pure C++11 in **one line** using any of `std::vector`s constructor overloads, without e.g. creating your own iterator adaptor.

It's trivial to do in *two* lines though, e.g.:

```
std::vector<Key> v;
for (const auto& p : m) v.push_back(p.first);
```

It would also be easy to create your own **iterator adaptor** for this purpose, for example:

```
template <typename InputIt>
struct key_it : public InputIt {
    key_it(InputIt it) : InputIt(it) {}
    auto operator*() { return (*this)->first; }
};

// Helper function for automatic deduction of iterator type.
template <typename InputIt>
key_it<InputIt> key_adapt(InputIt it) {
    return {it};
}
```

Now you can create and populate your `std::vector` in one line using:

```
std::vector<Key> v{key_adapt(std::begin(m)), key_adapt(std::end(m))};
```

<kbd>[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1051ce710c2b9400)</kbd>

Comment: I think a simple loop is probably as good as it gets then. Having to write my own functor/class is exactly what I hoped C++11 would allow me to avoid :(

Comment: @John I think that's as good as it gets, unless you want to plunge into the Boost mire...

Answer (score 1):

A slight refinement of [Quentin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403417/1245027):

```
std::vector<int> keys(map.size());
transform(map.begin(), map.end(), keys.begin(),
    [](std::pair<int, std::string> const &p) { return p.first; });
```

or more readably:

```
std::vector<int> keys(map.size());
auto get_key = [](std::pair<int, std::string> const &p) { return p.first; };
transform(map.begin(), map.end(), keys.begin(), get_key);
```

probably better having:

```
int get_key(std::pair<int, std::string> const &p) { return p.first; }

std::vector<int> get_keys(const std::map<int, std::string> &map)
{
    std::vector<int> keys(map.size());
    transform(map.begin(), map.end(), keys.begin(), get_key);
    return keys;
}
```

then calling:

```
std::vector<int> keys = get_keys(map);
```

if it's going to be used lots.

Comment: It does unnecessary default initialization of `vector`'s elements.

Comment: My lack of C++ experience showing :)  That may not be an issue though, depending on where you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::vector` class has two relevant constructors:

1. `vector(std::initializer_list<T>)` [C++11]
2. `vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)` [C++98]

The first is the new C++11 constructor that allows you to do things like:

```
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3 };
```

The second allows you to do things like:

```
std::vector<int> w{ v.rbegin(), v.rend() }; // 3, 2, 1
```

I don't see a way to use the `initializer_list` constructor (as you don't have the items available up-front), so your best bet would be to create a `key_iterator` class that works on a `std::map<T, K>::iterator` and returns `(*i).first` instead of `(*i)`. For example:

```
std::vector<int> keys{ key_iterator(m.begin()), key_iterator(m.end()) };
```

This also requires you to write the `key_iterator` class, which you can use the Boost iterator adapters to simplify the task. It may be easier just to use the 2 line version.

Answer (score 0):

**Whoopse, I realize this does not actually answer your question (must learn to read properly)!**

I would probably go with something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> m =
    {
        {1, "A"}, {2, "B"}, {3, "C"}
    };

    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(m.size());

    for(auto&& i: m)
        v.emplace_back(i.first);

    for(auto&& i: v)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```