# C++ SFML returning all sprites from map

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

currently i'm having problem with my code. I tried everything.
[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO5CU.png)
I hope someone can help me :). Btw i'm new to c++

Comment: Give [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110157/how-to-retrieve-all-keys-or-values-from-a-stdmap) a look

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: You are iterating over sprites.comp_value, which is a comparison function for the sprites in your map, and doesn't make sense in this context. I suggest trying: `for (auto sprite : sprites)` which will iterate over the keys. You can then access the values using `sprite.second`. This is assuming you're using the STL map container.

Comment: @Petar Putar Visnjic Could you please add your code as text in your question, this way it would be visible immediately and also be searchable. Also, please state what the problem is.

Comment: @PeterG. From the title, the OP is trying to get a collection (a `vector` here) containing all the sprites in their `sprites` collection, which seems to be a set or a map.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

std::map<std::string, sf::Sprite> sprites;

void addSprite(std::string sprite_name, sf::Texture sprite_texture) {

    sf::Sprite sprite;

    sprite.setTexture(sprite_texture);

    sprites[sprite_name] = sprite;

}

sf::Sprite getSprite(std::string sprite_name) {

    return sprites[sprite_name];
}

std::vector<sf::Sprite> getSprites() {

    std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites_c2;

    for each (sf::Sprite sprite in sprites.value_comp) {

        sprites_c2.emplace_back(sprite);

    }

    return sprites_c2;
}
```

Comment: You might want to edit your original post next time; this section is meant for people trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

`for each` is not valid C++; starting with C++11, the correct expression is
`for (<type> <variable> : <collection>)`

Here, you are also trying to access the collection of elements through `sprites.value_comp`, which is a function and doesn't make sense here.

Assuming `sprites` is a `std::set` container, you can iterate over it this way:

```
for (auto sprite : sprites) {
    // sprite is the value you're looking for
}
```

If you are using a `std::map` instead, use the same loop, but `sprite` will not contain your `sf::Sprite` but its key, and you will need to use `sprite.second` to access the sprite.

Note that the `auto` keyword lets the compiler determine the type of the variable.

If your compiler does not support C++11, you will need to do something like this instead:

```
std::set<sf::Sprite>::iterator it;
for (it = sprites.begin(); it != sprites.end(); ++it)
{
    // Access each sprite using *it (the star is necessary here)
}
```

With a `std::map`:

```
// Replace "keyType" with the type of the keys, such as int or std::string
std::map<keyType, sf::Sprite>::iterator it;    for (it = sprites.begin(); it != sprites.end(); ++it)
{
    // Access each sprite using it->second
}
```

If you are just trying to convert your `std::set` into a `std::vector`, however, there are easier ways to do that:

```
std::vector <sf::Sprite> sprites_c2;
std::copy(sprites.begin(), sprites.end(), std::back_inserter(sprites_c2));
```

For a `std::map` there aren't any single-line versions, so you will have to iterate with a loop as I stated above.

Comment: Note that there is an even simpler way, assuming you're just trying to convert a `std::set` into a `std::vector`: just create an empty vector and add `std::copy(sprites.begin(), sprites.end(), std::back_inserter(sprites_c2));
`