# std::map<string, string> to string (first values)

Tags: c++, string, c++11, dictionary, boost

I'd like to create `std::string` that contains first elements of `std::map<std::string, std::string>` separate by some delimiter (it can be from STL or Boost). 
Is there any better solution (one line) than loop? Like `boost::algorithm::join` for `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: It is unclear. Say you have a map with two elements. The output you are looking for is something like "key1 : value1, key2 : value2"?

Comment: see [How to retrieve all keys (or values) from a std::map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110157/how-to-retrieve-all-keys-or-values-from-a-stdmap),  modify the solutions to append to string

Comment: No, @Rerito . For: "key1 : value1, key2 : value2" and comma delimiter I'd like to have: "key1,key2".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done elegantly using Boost.Range's `map_keys` and Boost.StringAlgo's `join`:

```
std::string get_keys(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& map) {
  return boost::algorithm::join(
    map | boost::adaptors::map_keys,
    ", ");
}
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_keys.html

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use *boost*, then try [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
const std::string delimiter = "#";
const std::string result = std::accumulate(M.begin(), M.end(), std::string(),
[delimiter](const std::string& s, const std::pair<const std::string, std::string>& p) {
    return s + (s.empty() ? std::string() : delimiter) + p.first;
});
```

In the code above `M` is a `std::map<std::string, std::string>`.

Comment: `value_type` for `M` is `pair<const string, string>`. Note the extra `const`

Comment: would be nice to add: #include <numeric>

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm should be something like this:

```
std::string get_keys(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& map) {
  std::string result;
  std::for_each(map.cbegin(),
                map.cend(),
                [&result](const decltype(map)::value_type& p) {
                  result += p.first;
                  result += ", ";
                });

  // Erase the last ", " from the string, if present
  if (result.size() > 0) {
    result.erase(result.size() - 2, 2);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Essentially you have to cycle for each element in the map and add it into the string. The complexity is *O(N)* with *N* the number of element in the map.

You can improve the performance of the algorithm applying [`reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/) on the string result.

If you  know the average length of the *string key*, the you can initialize the variable with:

```
std::string result;
result.reserve(map.size() * AVG_LENGTH_STR_KEY);
```

This will improve a lot the `operator+=` operation in the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

As M.M. correctly pointed out, you can use [`boost::range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) for this (to which I added [`boost::string`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/string_algo.html)).

If your map is `m`, then the last line of

```
std::vector<std::string> o;
boost::copy(m | boost::adaptors::map_keys, std::back_inserter(o));
boost::algorithm::join(o, ", ");
```

is results. (Unfortunately, this requires a *huge* number of header files.)

**Example**

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
    m["hello"] = "world";
    m["goodbye"] = "now";

    std::vector<std::string> o;
    boost::copy(m | boost::adaptors::map_keys, std::back_inserter(o));
    std::cout << boost::algorithm::join(o, ", ") << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs

```
$ ./a.out 
goodbye, hello
$
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a json library such as the header only nlohmann::json

you can simply try casting it to a json in a single line.
note: be careful of exceptions.

```
std::cout << "My map or vector: " << ((json)myMap)) << "\n";
```

Edit: this might lazy i suppose but it gets the job done lol.